# "querySelectorAll()" with multiple conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api, logical-or, logical-and

Is it possible to make a search by `querySelectorAll()` using multiple unrelated conditions? If yes, how? And, how to specify whether those are AND or OR criteria?

For example:

How to find all **form**s, **p**s and **legend**s with a single `querySelectorAll()` call? Possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*AND or OR criteria*". Can you give an example for that?

Comment: [The documentation covers this in the first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 344, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a search by `querySelectorAll` using multiple unrelated conditions?

Yes, because `querySelectorAll` accepts full CSS selectors, and CSS has the concept of [*selector groups*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping), which lets you specify more than one unrelated selector. For instance:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("form, p, legend");
```

...will return a list containing any element that is a `form` **or** `p` **or** `legend`.

CSS also has the other concept: Restricting based on more criteria. You just combine multiple aspects of a selector. For instance:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div.foo");
```

...will return a list of all `div` elements that *also* (**and**) have the class `foo`, ignoring other `div` elements.

You can, of course, combine them:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div.foo, p.bar, div legend");
```

...which means "Include any `div` element that also has the `foo` class, any `p` element that also has the `bar` class, and any `legend` element that's also inside a `div`."

Comment: is there a possibility to use a single class from document.querySelectorAll, for example I have var hotspots = document.querySelectorAll(".clickMapItem.text , .clickMapItem.multiImageText"); var i;
                for (i = 0; i < hotspots.length; i++) {
                    hotspots[i].style.display = "none";
                } I need to use if else statement, how to check whether it is a class display none or something else. if (hotspots[0 or 1].style.display == "none") doesn't work.

Comment: @MileMijatovic: Questions should be posted as questions rather than comments. But see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238153/how-to-get-background-color-property-value-in-javascript/25238247#25238247

Comment: Ok, but in general, is it possible to do what I asked? The link did not help

Comment: The selector groups concept worked for me still in 2018... thanks for sharing

Comment: Year after year, I still use `document.querySelectorAll("div.foo", "div.bar")` and it never worked. Code UX is the next UX ;)

Comment: @GabrielGlenn indeed it doesn't work. Try the following instead: `document.querySelectorAll("div.foo, div.bar")`... it will. In your approach it will get the first item only "div.foo", but not the second. To work you need to remove the central double quotes and keep just the first and the last one...

Answer (score 37):

According to the documentation, just like with any css selector, you can specify as many conditions as you want, and they are treated as logical 'OR'.

> This example returns a list of all div elements within the document
>   with a class of either "note" or "alert":

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.note, div.alert");
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Meanwhile to get the 'AND' functionality you can for example simply use a multiattribute selector, as jquery says:

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

ex. `"input[id][name$='man']"`  specifies both id and name of the element and both conditions must be met. For classes it's as obvious as "`.class1.class2`" to require object of 2 classes.

All possible combinations of both are valid, so you can easily get equivalent of more sophisticated 'OR' and 'AND' expressions.

Comment: While the method itself is correct, there's no need to reference jQuery to explain CSS (especially since the OP's question is limited to JavaScript).

Comment: doesn't hurt I guess :) a quick way to figure out more options for those not working with CSS on daily basis

Answer (score 9):

With pure JavaScript you can do this (such as SQL) and anything you need, basically:

```html
<html>

<body>

<input type='button' value='F3' class="c2" id="btn_1">
<input type='button' value='F3' class="c3" id="btn_2">
<input type='button' value='F1' class="c2" id="btn_3">

<input type='submit' value='F2' class="c1" id="btn_4">
<input type='submit' value='F1' class="c3" id="btn_5">
<input type='submit' value='F2' class="c1" id="btn_6">

<br/>
<br/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var arrFiltered = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=F2][type=submit][class=c1]');

            arrFiltered.forEach(function (el)
            {                
                var node = document.createElement("p");
                
                node.innerHTML = el.getAttribute('id');

                window.document.body.appendChild(node);
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question, specifically the `how to specify whether those are AND or OR criteria` part, see accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

With [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

- **Logical AND (&&)** can be archived by specifying elements and attributes without commas.
- **Logical OR (||)** can be archived by specifying elements and attributes with commas.

For example, there is 2 forms as shown below:

```html
<form class="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="fruits" value="Apple">
  <p id="p1">Orange</p>
</form>
<form class="form2" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="input2" name="fruits" value="Banana">
  <p id="p2">Kiwi</p>
</form>
```

#### <Logical AND (&&)>

Then, you can select **Apple's `<input>`** and **Banana's `<input>`** with `[name="fruits"]` as shown below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="fruits"]');
// Apple's <input> and Banana's <input>
```

Now by specifying elements and attributes without commas, you can select only **Apple's `<input>`** as shown below:

```js
                        // ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓  ↓ ↓ ↓               ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓     
document.querySelectorAll('form.form1 input[name="fruits"][id="input1"]');
// Apple's <input>
```

In addition, you can replace `.form1` with `[class="form1"]` and `[id="input1"]` with `#input1` as shown below:

```js
                        //         .form1                       [id="input1"]
                        //     ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓                     ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
document.querySelectorAll('form[class="form1"] input[name="fruits"]#input1');
// Apple's <input>
```

#### <Logical OR (||)>

Next, you can select **Apple's `<input>`** with `#input1` as shown below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#input1');
// Apple's <input>
```

Now by specifying elements and attributes with commas, you can select **Apple's `<input>`**, **Orange's `<p>`**, **Banana's `<input>`** and **Kiwi's `<p>`** as shown below:

```js
                        //          ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓  ↓     
document.querySelectorAll('#input1, #input2, p');
                        //        ↑        ↑
// Apple's <input>, Orange's <p>, Banana's <input> and Kiwi's <p>
```

#### <Logical AND (&&)> and <Logical OR (||)>

In addition, of course, you can use both **Logical AND** and **Logical OR** together as shown below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input#input1, input#input2, p#p1')[
// Apple's <input>, Orange's <p> and Banana's <input>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using just `document.querySelectorAll('selector1, selector2, selector3')` didn't work for me, had to use `forEach()` method alongside to achieve the desired result.

```
document.querySelectorAll('selector1, selector2, selector3').forEach(item => {
        item.//code
    })
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2, #id3').style = 'background-color: red';
document.querySelectorAll('#id4, #id5, #id6').forEach(item => {
    item.style = 'background-color: red';
})
```

```html
<div id="id1">id1</div>
<div id="id2">id2</div>
<div id="id3">id3</div>
<div id="id4">id4</div>
<div id="id5">id5</div>
<div id="id6">id6</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) does take a [group of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping):

```
form, p, legend
```