# What is the difference between the following two statements using the querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

If I use the following javascript function with CSS selector value of
**"#game  .screen.active"** as argument

```
var activeScreen = document.querySelectorAll("#game  .screen.active")[0];
```

The above statement will assign to the **activeScreen** variable the document element with
id="game" and class="screen" which is currently an **active** screen.

I have the following question :
1. Is that true, that there will be only one **active screen** at any point in time?
2. If you provide **more than one** CSS selectors as argument to the **querySelectorAll()** function,
do we have to seperate them using **comma**(',') like the below statement?

```
var activeScreen = document.querySelectorAll("#game,  .screen.active")[0];
```

What is the difference between the above two statements, one with the comma and one without
the comma?

---

### The Structure of my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script src="scripts/gameEngine.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div class="screen" id="splash-screen">
            <h1 class="logo">Ninja <br/>Warrior</h1>
            <span class="continue">Click to continue</span>
        </div>
        <div class="screen" id="main-menu"></div>
        <div class="screen" id="game-screen"></div>
        <div class="screen" id="high-scores"></div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[html](/questions/tagged/html) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: These are css selectoors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

When using `querySelectorAll`, you can specify **multiple selectors** by using the comma `,` inside of it.  Separating ids, class names, element names, etc. with a **space** is **descendant selection**.

So, by using `#game .screen.active`, you are saying **target #game's child element(s) that have the class screen and have the class active**.  So, you could be targeting multiple elements, but they would not include the `#game` element.

But, by using `#game, .screen.active` you are targeting **both** the `#game` element and any element with both classes `screen` and `active`.

[Refer to this article from the Mozilla Developer Network about combinators and selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors)

Comment: Thanks @Marcus Parsons 

Answer (score 0):

*Is that true, that there will be only one active screen at any point in time?*

Not necessarily. You could have more and they'd be selected with that class. You have control over it (but avoid repeated ids).

*If you provide more than one CSS selectors as argument to the querySelectorAll() function, do we have to seperate them using comma(',') like the below statement?*

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001943/819651)

- `#game  .screen.active` means: get me anything with the classes `.screen` and `.active` **under** id `#game`
- `#game,  .screen.active` means: get me what has the id `#game` **and** anything with the classes `.screen` and `.active` (regardless of inside or outside `#game`)

Comment: Thanks @Luis Soares, when someone is playing games on a PC, mobile phone, isn't it there will be 1 screen loaded at any point in time, I cannot think of a scenario where there will be **more than 1 screen** loaded?

Comment: In you application logic, you're right. I was being generic.