# IF any of a series of class names exist, then do stuff

Tags: javascript, if-statement, css-selectors

I'd like to run an IF statement whereby it runs if any one of a series of specific class names exist on the page somewhere. I currently have this method, but when the script runs, it only pays attention to the first class name in the list and then ignores the rest.

```
if (document.querySelector('.class_a'||'.class_b'||'.class_c')) { // do stuff }
```

Any ideas on how I can execute this fairly simple command please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelectorAll with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001917/queryselectorall-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Thank you - I tried it though, and it always returns true, even if the elements don't exist on the page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `,` is what you want to use to [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#grouping_selectors) selectors so

```
if (document.querySelector('.class_a, .class_b, .class_c')) {
 // do stuff 
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it only returns true if the first element exists (.class_a), ignoring the rest.

Comment: @ChuwaFeet this selector combined with `querySelector` will select only the first one, of all the classes, in the DOM it finds. Do you want to select more than the first found element ? Do you care which elements exist or only care to know if any of them exist in the DOM ?

Comment: Hi Gabriele, yes that's correct - I don't need all of the elements to be true in the list, however i need the function to run if any one or more of the elements exists. ie if .class_a isn't in the DOM, then I want the script to fire if .class_b exists instead.

Comment: @ChuwaFeet then this code should do that. Are those elements added dynamically ? If so you would need to run the code **after** adding them to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you - you're right. Seems like it was an issue with the timing of when the scripts were firing. Many thanks my man. Do you have paypal? I'd like to buy you a drink.

Comment: @ChuwaFeet lol, that is alright :) I am glad i could help. You can accept the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the selector, separating with "," character.

```
if (document.querySelector('.class_a, .class_b, .class_c')) { // do stuff }
```

Comment: I also tried this and it only returns true if the first element exists (.class_a), ignoring the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the revision. However, now it's just returning false all the time, rather than true :(