# Change Text color of an ul with a Javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I need to create a button to change my li's to black.

html

```
 <h2>Sonnenfarben</h2>
  <div class="box">
     
    <ul type="circle" class="liste2">
      <li class="farbeRot">rot</li>
      <li class="farbeOrange">orange</li>
      <li class="farbeGelb">gelb</li>
    </ul>
    
    <button onclick="changeColor()">Lights out</button>

  <ol class="liste3" start="3">
      <li class="farbeBraun">braun</li>
      <li class="farbeGrau">grau</li>
  </ol>
```

css

```
.farbeRot{
  color: ;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.farbeOrange{
  color: orange;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGelb{
  color: yellow;
}

.farbeBraun{
  color: brown;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGrau{
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box{
  color: black;
}
```

JS

```
function changeColor(){
  document.querySelector('.box').style.color = "black";
}
```

Tried to connect everything but didn´t work out.

edit: put in all colors I defined already. Tried deleting them etc. but it still did not work.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.box').style.color = "black"` is the same like `.box{color: black;}` which make it not show effect

Comment: Have in mind that there isn't a closing div tag for your box div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just wanna change your li's color by a click event, don't do it that manually(almost). write a CSS-styled class for your ul and toggle it on click event

```js
function changeColor() {
  const liste2 = document.querySelector(".liste2");
  liste2.classList.toggle("black-ul")
  
  /*
  if you just want the lights off and not toggle, replace above "toggle" with "add"
  simple javascript my boy
  */
  
}
```

```css
.farbeRot{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.farbeOrange{
  color: orange;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGelb{
  color: pink;
}

.farbeBraun{
  color: brown;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGrau{
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box{
  color: black;
}


/* below code is to make all the li black */

.black-ul > li {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
     
    <ul type="circle" class="liste2">
      <li class="farbeRot">rot</li>
      <li class="farbeOrange">orange</li>
      <li class="farbeGelb">gelb</li>
    </ul>
    
    <button onclick="changeColor()">Toggle light</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A toggle button would even be better, thx. I copied everything but it sadly doesn´t work out

Comment: then the issue might be on any other part of your code. are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: Solved everything thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the default color of `.box` from `black` to other values,such as red or green

```
.box{
  color: red;
}
```

```js
function changeColor(){
  let lis = document.querySelectorAll('.liste2 > li,liste3 > li');
  for(let i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
    lis[i].style.color = "black";
  }
}
```

```css
.farbeRot{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.farbeOrange{
  color: orange;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGelb{
  color: yellow;
}

.farbeBraun{
  color: brown;
  font-style: italic;
}

.farbeGrau{
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sonnenfarben</h2>
  <div class="box">
     
    <ul type="circle" class="liste2">
      <li class="farbeRot">rot</li>
      <li class="farbeOrange">orange</li>
      <li class="farbeGelb">gelb</li>
    </ul>
   

  <ol class="liste3" start="3">
      <li class="farbeBraun">braun</li>
      <li class="farbeGrau">grau</li>
  </ol>
  
   <button onclick="changeColor()">Lights out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Stil doesn´t work. I defined colors for every li before already. Is that causing an error?

Comment: @Pekz Can you add full code so that we can analysis it

Comment: @Pekz if you override the color by setting a style to the list-items then you must set the color using the same selector and not the parent list element.

Comment: @lucumt edited the code in

Comment: @Pekz You need to follow  Fabrizio Calderan's comment,that's the reason,you can check my updated answer now

Comment: @lucumt Thank you very much! Finally understood it now

Comment: @lucumt actually forgot another ol in my html code... could you explain how i combine it with my ul so those colors will change to black aswell? <.<

Comment: @Pekz you can check this [queryselectorall-with-multiple-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001917/queryselectorall-with-multiple-conditions),I have updated my ansewr,just using `document.querySelectorAll('.liste2 > li,liste3 > li')` can do it

Comment: @Pekz hmmm,why not mark my ansewr as unaccepted?