# How to access a class within a parent element in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Looked in the 'Similar Questions' list and found one that was almost what I needed, but not quite...
What I need is to modify the properties of a class that is within 3 different elements.

Thanks for your input, David - Here's a more complete rundown:

HTML:

```
<div id="col1" name="col1">
  <div (or image, etc.)></div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div (or image, etc.)></div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div (or image, etc.)></div>
</div>

<div id="col2" name="col2">
  <div (or image, etc.)></div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div (or image, etc.)></div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div (or image, etc.)></div>
</div>
```

If I were to use CSS it would look like:

```
#col1 .spacer{
  height:10px;
}

#col2 .spacer{
  height:15px;
}
etc...
```

but I want to control the classes dynamically using JS

I'm familiar with document.getElementById and document.getElementsByClassName, but can't seem to get the syntax right to access the class within each ID.

@Mohamed Mostafa wrote:

```
var col1Spacers = document.querySelectorAll('#col1 .spacer');
col1Spacers.forEach(function(spacer) {
spacer.style.height = '10px';
});
```

which looks promising - still not working, but can you clarify - in the statement:

```
var col1Spacers = document.querySelectorAll('#col1 .spacer');
```

does that create an *array* called col1Spacers?

Making progress - having what looks like a weird prob:
I define 3 querySelectorAll objects (arrays?)and then create an array of those objects, like so:

```
var col1spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col1 .spacer');
alert(col1spacer.length);
var col2spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col2 .spacer');
alert(col2spacer.length);
var col3spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col3 .spacer');    
alert(col3spacer.length);
const columnSpacer = ['col1spacer', 'col2spacer', 'col3spacer'];
alert(columnSpacer[0].length + ', ' + columnSpacer[1].length + ', ' + columnSpacer[2].length);
```

the colspacer lengths are displayed as expected: '11', '10', & '9'. However, the last alert returns '10, 10, 10'. Can I not create an array of querySelectorAll objects without equalizing their lengths?

Comment: What about using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead?

Comment: @GrafiCode How is that a relevant dupe target? OP is asking how they would select all the elements that match those CSS selector, not the difference between the returned collections. A more suitable dupe target would be ["querySelectorAll()" with multiple conditions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001917/queryselectorall-with-multiple-conditions-in-javascript).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.  It sounds like you're trying to access HTML elements with JavaScript code, neither of which are shown in the question.  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates what you're attempting and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: @kelsny yes, that' definitely better

Comment: Friendly advice: don't use id components ("#col1") in CSS rules. They really make life miserable in the long run because of the way CSS specificity rules work. *e*: I'm from Dallas CJ, you can trust me.

Comment: Maybe `document.querySelectorAll('[id^=col] .spacer')` is what you want? This finds the `.spacer` elements within all the IDs that begin with `col`.

Comment: And I concur with @Pointy. If you find yourself reating a bunch of `#colX` IDs, give those elements a common class: `class="col"`. Then the selector becomes `.col .spacer`

Answer (score 0):

you can use querySelectorAll to get all of those you want like so :

```
 // reflects only spacer inside col1 
var col1Spacers = document.querySelectorAll('#col1 .spacer');
col1Spacers.forEach(function(spacer) {
spacer.style.height = '10px';
});
```

Comment: Still wrestling with it... Updated OP

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
var colSpacers = document.querySelectorAll('.spacer');
colSpacers.forEach(e=>{
if(e.parentNode.id == "col1"){
    e.style.height = '10px';
}else if(e.parentNode.id == "col2"){
    e.style.height = '15px';
}
else{
    e.style.height = '20px';
}
    
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution - Thanks to all who added their advice, couldn't have done it without you!

The reason for this endeavor was to equalize the heights of the content in 3 columns, so that the bottoms of the columns line up. I had already made a script that did this on a particular webpage, but I had to use coding that was specific to that page. I posted this question so that I could make the script more generic, as I have other pages where I need to use it.

So here's what I came up with - it's been 15 years since I used JS on a regular basis, so please forgive me if it's a little sloppy:

```
function columnAdjust(){

    var col1 = document.getElementById('col1');
    var col2 = document.getElementById('col2');
    var col3 = document.getElementById('col3');
    
    const columnHeights = [col1.offsetHeight, col2.offsetHeight, col3.offsetHeight];
    var largestHeight = Math.max(columnHeights[0], columnHeights[1], columnHeights[2]);

    var col1spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col1 .spacer');
    var col2spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col2 .spacer');
    var col3spacer = document.querySelectorAll('#col3 .spacer');    
    const columnSpacer = [col1spacer, col2spacer, col3spacer];

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < columnHeights.length; i++) {
        if (columnHeights[i] != largestHeight) {
            for (let j = 0; j < columnSpacer[i].length; j++) {
                columnSpacer[i][j].style.height = (largestHeight - columnHeights[i]) / (columnSpacer[i].length) + 5 + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I welcome any comments/criticism/advice. Y'all have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

After you posted your own solution I now think I understand what you want to do. While showing your code attempts is good, next time try to explain what you want to achieve.

This can be very easily done without JavaScript and instead CSS:

```css
.equal-columns {
  display: flex;
}
.equal-columns > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 5px;
}
.equal-columns > div > div {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="equal-columns">
  <div>
    <div>A</div>

    <div>B</div>

    <div>C</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>A<br>A</div>

    <div>B</div>

    <div>C<br>C<br>C</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>A</div>

    <div>B<br>B</div>

    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some general remarks:

- Avoid "spacer" elements. Use `margin` instead.
- `name` on `div`s are pointless.

Comment: Great answer! I had tried using CSS with the 'table' property, but it didn't adjust the height of the content within the divs. This is a much more concise solution. As for the 'name' property, it's an old habit - to make compatible with older versions of Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

**we can use :deep syntax in vue js. To access a class from its parent element.**