# How to know button's background color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a yellow button.

When I click the button, I want to get the button's color.

I tried this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style rel="stylesheet">
    .A {
      background-color: #ffff00
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function clicked() {
      console.log(document.getElementById("A1").style.backgroundColor);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="A1" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked()">
</body>

</html>
```

then I got nothing.

How can I get 'yellow' or '#ffff00'?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get \`background-color\` property value in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238153/how-to-get-background-color-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `getComputedStyle` method to get the button style:

```js
function clicked() {
  var button = document.getElementById("A1");
  var style = getComputedStyle(button);
  
  console.log(style['background-color']);
}
```

```css
.A { background-color: #ffff00 }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="A1" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked()">
```

Comment: Wow! Then do you know how to change rgb to string?

Comment: That is a `String`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS

```
<style rel="stylesheet">
    .A { background-color: #ffff00 }
</style>
```

You must write this way

```
<input type="button" id="A1" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked()">

    <script>
    function clicked() {
    const element = document.getElementById('A1');
    const style = getComputedStyle(element);
        console.log(style.backgroundColor);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

> The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

Then you have to convert the *rgb* value to *hex*.

You can try the following way:

```js
function clicked(el) {
  var bg_color = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).backgroundColor;
  bg_color = bg_color.match(/\d+/g);
  console.log(rgbToHex(bg_color));
}
    
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(+rgb[0]) + componentToHex(+rgb[1]) + componentToHex(+rgb[2]);
}
```

```css
.A { background-color: #ffff00 }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="A1" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this)">
```